# Javascript XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://XX.XX.XX. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: soap, xmlhttprequest

My Client have a Web Service running at their server that accepts Soap request and returns soap response. The only thing i have with me is the IP address at which it is running, Port and some sample Soap request strings. 
      The Problem is when i run the Soap request with given IP address and SOAP request string in SOA-Client of Mozilla, am getting response properly. But when i try to achieve the same in my local project am getting "**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**" Error. Please find the Below Code Which am using.

var xmhtp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
            xmhtp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmhtp.readyState == 4 && xmhtp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("dvResponse").innerHTML = xmhtp.responseText;
                }
            };


            var sr = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
                     '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ' +
                    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                    'xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" ' +
                    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                    'xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                    '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                    '<m:dcGetProd xmlns:m="urn:abc.aa">' +
                    '<startTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-11-30T08:00:00</startTime>' +
                    '<endTime xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2016-01-11T18:15:00</endTime>' +
                    '<dcName xsi:type="xsd:string">Example1</dcName>' +
                    '</m:dcGetProd>' +
                    '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                    '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

            xmhtp.open("POST", "http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:80/", true);

            // Send the POST request
            xmhtp.send(sr);
```

Please Help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Web Service you are calling at `http://xx.xx.xx.xx` is not returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in its Response header, and therefore the request is being denied because of the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) spec.

You can [read more about CORS here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Your Web Service will need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the Response header of the service in order for you to get past this error. The solution for this will depend on the type of web server hosting the service.